# What happens if a rogue TCP server refuses to send one number from its TCP sequence?

Tags: tcp

What happens if a rogue TCP server refuses to send one number from its TCP sequence?  I assume the client will request
that number over and over, but will the client's OS ever allow an app to see the rest of the stream if the number never
comes?  In my case, I'm using Chrome in Windows 10, but curious if there are differences across standard systems.

My original question was "What happens if an http server just assumes all ACK packets are normal when it gets
very busy?", but I see too many problems with that question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TCP packet is not requested by the client, it's resent automatically by the server if not acknowledged after timeout. A 'rogue' server will simply let the whole connection time out.

(TCP has no client or server roles, I'm using these terms for simplicity from the upper level protocol that often do.)

If a packet is missing the application will not see what the stack may have received beyond this point.

Comment: OK, thanks, that sounds reasonable: All OS/Browser systems will effectively freeze at any glitch even if the server were to send all of the following packets. Still, it's a bit of a shame that Youtube, for example, playing in my browser, wouldn't be allowed to work with the extra packets and show me something. (But, by the same token, I can see showing them as a little security risk. And, yes, I'm aware of the UDP option, but taking our predominantly TCP world as a given and just wondering what more we could get for free when routes are noisy or busy.)

Comment: @bobuhito, "_taking our predominantly TCP world as a given_" would be a huge mistake.Many things use UDP, including games, voice and video. TCP is not appropriate for real-time traffic.